# Natural Order should be maintained while ordinal encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, data-cleaning, feature-engineering

I am encoding my ordinal categorical values as VHigh=1, High=2,Med=3,Low=4. Am I doing correct? or order doesn't impact?

If it impacts, how does it impact Decision Tree, Logistic Regression, SVM?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you have Ordinal features you want to preserve the order of the classes so that the model learns the order as well. This gives the model an extra layer of information which it can use during prediction. So yes you should use an encoder which preserves this order.

The kind of encoding you use will have an impact on the model performance. If you have multiple encoders, you should try and see which one gives the best performance.

**Cheers!**

Comment: Make Sense, thank you

Comment: If you found this answer helpful kindly upvote and accept is as the answer so that others can benefit from this too!